# how to get data from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am new to firebase..

I am trying to assign more info about users register in my app and as name,password,email,image are not enough for each user. so i decided to use the UID as a key to each user and store that in database then i can grab later.
so if the user login any other time i want retrieve this data **these data wont be changed again** so setvalue() and add listener to change wont work with me so in order to do so i coded

```
Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

what should i do next?!

the guide doesnt say any info about equalto(),how to use query or how to retrieve data without listeners

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase retrieval queries are asynchronous, there is no "official" way of doing it synchronous (without callbacks/listeners).

**Why is it Asynchronous?**

Because Firebase is cloud-based, it needs to do network calls to do any CRUD operation.

Now that you have your `Query` object, you can simply attach a `ValueEventListener` and receive your data in a `DataSnapShot`.

Note: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener)` only queries once, in oppose to `addValueEventListener(listener)`.

it would look like this :

```
q.addValueEventListener(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // for example: if you're expecting your user's data as an object of the "User" class.
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // read query is cancelled.
            }
        });
```

for more info refer to this [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)

Edit: Event listeners are initially triggered once, then triggered whenever the data you're querying on changes.

Comment: but these valueEventlistener is trigered only when data is changed right?

Comment: Good question, forgot to mention that they're triggered initially once, then they're triggered whenever the data you're querying on changes, Edited.

Comment: can you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862282/how-to-make-sure-query-is-not-empty

Answer (score 3):

You can just use:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
Query q= usersRef.orderByKey().equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

Then attach a listener to your query to get the data.

```
q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()){  }
```

Otherwise you can structure your data in this way:

```
users:
|-uid1 :
|-uid2 :
|-uid3 :
```

In this way you have just to use this code to retrieve the DatabaseReference of your user:

```
String uid= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

every one i found that firebase event listeners are need some time to perform their task so i used just flag and some thread concept to achieve best compatibility with firebase data retrievine

```
static long[] COUNTER_VAR;
static String STRING_VAR[];
final static int TOTAL_FLAGS = 10;



DATA_RECEIVED = new boolean[TOTAL_FLAGS];
COUNTER_VAR = new long[TOTAL_FLAGS];
STRING_VAR = new String[TOTAL_FLAGS];
INDEX_DATA_R = 0;

void increment`enter code here`_DataReceiveIndex(){
    if(INDEX_DATA_R<TOTAL_FLAGS-1) {
        INDEX_DATA_R += 1;
    }else{
        INDEX_DATA_R = 0;
    }
}

public int getCount(final String path) {
    final int cur = INDEX_DATA_R;
    DATA_RECEIVED[cur] = false;
    INDEX_DATA_R++;
    mDatabaseReference.child(path).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            COUNTER_VAR[cur] = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                DATA_RECEIVED[cur] = true;
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return cur;
}


public boolean setIds() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int a = getCount(APPOINT_PATH);

            while(!DATA_RECEIVED[a]) {
            }

            total_appointment = COUNTER_VAR[a];
            mDatabaseReference.child("/ID/A").setValue(total_appointment);
       }
   }).start();

}
```