# how to make sure Query is not empty

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have an application with many types of users like normalUser,PremiumUser

and in order to define that i use their unique UID in firebasedatabase to each one in their category premium or normal

this is my database firebase shape

```
--users
-----normal
-----premium
```

so if user choose normal account he will be assigned to normal only

for me this is how to grab his data later when he log in is as follows

```
if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        finish();
        Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("normal").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        Query q2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("premium").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        if (q != null) {
            q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Normal.class));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        } else {
            q2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Premium.class));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

but looks like the code enter both activities altough for sure this account exists in one of categories only(normal or premium)

i tried using

```
if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0) //none of both activities is entered
if (dataSnapshot != null)//both Activites still entered
if(dataSnapshot.getValue(Premium.class)!=null)//vvvv
if(dataSnapshot.getValue(Normal.class)!=null)//but still none entered
```

i also tried

```
Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("normal").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
final Query q2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("premium").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Normal.class));
    }
    else {
        q2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Premium.class));
            }
```

but none  of them was entered too

how can i fix that

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by adding to each user a uid then changed

```
 Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("normal").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
 Query q2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("premium").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

to the following

```
 Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("normal").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
 Query q2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("premium").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

i still dont know why the first way is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your query will never be null, because you created it just before that. There is no way to know how many results a query has without attaching a listener.

So the closest you can get with your current data structure is to nest the queries:

```
Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("normal").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
Query q2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("premium").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Normal.class));
        }
        else {
            q2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Premium.class));
                }
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

A more direct way to make this work is to change your data structure so that is also contains the payment status for each user. So also store:

```
user_payment_status
  uid1: "normal"
  uid2: "premium"
```

Then you can simply look up the status for the current user with a single value listener. You'll keep your current list around, since you likely also want to show a list of all premium users somewhere in the app.

Duplicating data in this way is quite common in NoSQL databases.

Comment: still didnt work i  just added  if (dataSnapshot.exists()) { for the startActivity premium to make sure

Comment: beside i cant just state payment status because each one will have very different things almost nothing common